# How to Name Python Sessions from Powershell Script?

Tags: python, powershell, asynchronous, process, invoke-command

I am executing multiple python processes asynchronously from powershell, but I am not able to distinguish between them which can cause problems when I want to kill a process. As such, I'd like to be able to add a unique id to each of the processes. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

I've tried the following:

```
    $cred = Get-QRemote-Credential
    $TimeOut = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeoutMSec (New-TimeSpan -Days 7).TotalMilliSeconds
    $sessionID = "processID rhun"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {powershell -c "$Using:pname '$Using:scriptPath' $Using:pargs"} -InDisconnectedSession -SessionName $sessionID -SessionOption $TimeOut -ConfigurationName QRemoteConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the `-AsJob` parameter to track processes?

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {$tmp = Get-ChildItem ".\"} -asjob -jobname "pid3" -computer localhost | out-null
invoke-command -scriptblock {$svc = get-service} -asjob -jobname "pid1" -computer localhost | out-null
invoke-command -scriptblock {ping google.com} -asjob -jobname "pid2" -computer localhost | out-null
get-job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
3      pid3            RemoteJob       Completed     True            localhost            $tmp = Get-ChildItem ".\"
5      pid1            RemoteJob       Completed     True            localhost            $svc = get-service
7      pid2            RemoteJob       Running       True            localhost            ping google.com
```

The `-JobName` parameter allows you to create a name for the process. You can use `Remove-Job` to remove completed or failed processes. You can use `Stop-Job` to halt them.`Get-Job` allows you to track the status of the jobs you have started.

If you like using interactive sessions, you can enter your remote PSSession and start a job there.

See [about_Remote_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs?view=powershell-6) for more possibilities.